# Trying to animate a div to grow inside to show its content inside another div

Tags: html, css

I am getting a strange happening here. I have a div inside another div. And I want the main div to stay in place and when the mouse hovers on it the nested div inside the main div animates to a certain height within it to show some text. What happens instead is that my main div for some reason drops down in its position. Quick .GIF to show the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxQ14.jpg

```
<div id={`SlideBarBox-${this.props.title}`} className="SlideBarBox">
      <div className="SlideBarBox-Info" id={`info-${this.props.title}`}>
            <h4 id={`text-${this.props.title}`}>{this.props.title}</h4>
      </div>
</div>
.SlideBarBox {
    width: 25%;
    height: 34%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-right: 4%;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

.SlideBarBox-Info{
    height: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
    -moz-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
    -o-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
    transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1); 
    overflow: hidden;  
}
```

And my animation:

```
document.getElementById(`SlideBarBox-${this.props.title}`).addEventListener("mouseout", (event) => {
    document.getElementById(`info-${this.props.title}`).style.height = "0px";
})
document.getElementById(`SlideBarBox-${this.props.title}`).addEventListener("mouseover", (event) =>{
    document.getElementById(`info-${this.props.title}`).style.height = "20px";
})
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does that 20px in your style.height have anything to do with it?

Comment: That increases the height of the div that shows the text. So I start the height of the div at 0 and then I set it to 20. And because of the transition it animates.

Comment: Also if I take out the text out of the nested div it animates appropriately without dropping the main div.

Comment: You'll have better luck getting help if you can reproduce your issue in isolation using something like CodePen or JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to go at this in a round about way. You can achieve this with simple HTML and CSS with now JS necessary. Also, I'm not familiar with what you're trying to achieve with your HTML with the squiggly brackets in the IDs, but I'm certain that `className` is not how you identify a class in HTML. You'll want to use just `class=`.

I've put together an example of how to do this with HTML and CSS here. In your CSS you'll want to give the parent div the attribute `position: relative;` and the child div the attribute `position: absolute;`.  Absolute positioning will keep the child div from affecting the height of the parent div. The `left` and `bottom` attribute will locate the child div where you're wanting it in the parent div.

From there you'll want the `:hover` on the parent div to affect the `max-height` of the child div. Use max-height because, for some reason, `height` is not affected by CSS transitions. So the div won't gradually grow, but will simply jump to full height as soon as you hover.

In general you'll want to look for ways to achieve things using CSS before trying to do it in Javascript, as CSS is lighter weight and handled much quicker by the browser.

```css
h4 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.SlideBarBox {
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-right: 4%;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

.SlideBarBox-Info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
    -moz-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
    -o-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
    transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1); 
    overflow: hidden;  
}

.SlideBarBox:hover .SlideBarBox-Info {
  max-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="" class="SlideBarBox">
      <div class="SlideBarBox-Info" id="">
            <h4 id="">iFavMovie</h4>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're solution did work in 2 suprising ways. Although the animation that happened was too quick. But looking through your code I was reminded of how to use absolute inside a relative div and that solved my problem. I am still figuring out all that stuff and how it affects different display properties like flex and inline. So thank you very much my good sir! (On a side note all those braces are for React JSX and className has to be used cause class is a javascript keyword.)

Comment: You're welcome! The animation speed was copied over from your CSS, so you should be able to change it easily by editing it in the `.SlideBarBox-Info` class.